# woocommerce modal bootstraap

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make a modal window with woocommerce variables ($product) but I'm stuck on the modal

this my code but it doesn't work because first, my modal is behind my black filter and second, I need the id for my product and the problem is that I take just the first id when a click on each button

[example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjesY.png)
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fH7N.png)

```
    echo '<a href='.get_permalink($product_id).'?sku='.$product->get_sku().'><button class="second_content">en savoir plus '. $product->get_sku().'</button></a><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>';

   echo '    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">'.$product->get_sku().'
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to set the SKU using JavaScript when the modal is triggered

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var sku = e.relatedTarget.attr('id');
    // Alternatively you could parse the href attribute to get the sku from your url
    $('#skuId').html(sku)
})
```

Then just modify your first line to be

```
echo '<a href='.get_permalink($product_id).'?sku='.$product->get_sku().' id='.$product->get_sku().'><button class="second_content">en savoir plus '. $product->get_sku().'</button></a><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>';
```

And your modal to be

```
echo '
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content"><div id="skuId">[set on show]</div>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>';
```

Please note I have not tested the specifics but the overall idea should work with a couple of modifications.

Comment: I don't see the need for the sku query??